# password_verify is not returning true

Tags: php

I am using password_hash to encrypt a password for inserting into a database. It is working but when I use `password_verify` to verify it is always returning false, even though the encrypted value is the same (checked the database's values)

Here is my code:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=pass;host=localhost", "root", "");

    $select = $dbh->query("SELECT username, password FROM passwords WHERE username = " . $dbh->quote($_POST['username']));

    $fetch = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (password_verify($fetch['password'], password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT))) {
        echo 'Welcome! ' . $fetch['username'] . " your password is " . $fetch['password'];
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

The encrypted password in the database is

> $2y$10$dMXgvPo5j9.8gaSqgtxTSevlFCsJwdSn8vdLbqFirUQcFvzfk0or2

Am I missing something? I've used different hashing functions in PHP (`hash()`), so I am kind of confused about why this is not working. The password inserted was encrypted in the database via `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The syntax is `password_verify($unhashed, $hashed);` - see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) - so for your specific code, it'd be `password_verify($_POST['password'], $fetch['password']);`

Comment: $_POST['password'] is unhashed.

Comment: the manual says string password, int algorithm for password_hash() so what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rehash the password when verifying.

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $fetch['password']);
```

Plus you had them in the wrong order.

Comment: got to wait 9 minutes but I will mark it when the time is up

Comment: No problem, have a few "open answers" flying around and I love rep. :P

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `password_verify()` is, from the documentation

> boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )

This means that there are only 2 arguments, and that yours are in the wrong order. This in addition to that the `$password` string is the unhashed variable.

Simply change it to

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $fetch['password']);
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @user2101411 Already mentioned this to you in the comments, but I figured I'd post an answer too ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: sorry, I didn't see it in the wrong order, my mistake, but thanks for pointing it out :)